# Downloading and renaming a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hit a URL to download a file and rename the file I get as response using javascript. I tried the following code but its not working. The file is getting downloaded but renaming is not happening

```
function downloadAndRename(url, fileName){
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    $('body').append(anchor);
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = fileName;
    anchor.click();
}
```

Is there any other way by which I can do this?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: if you handle it client side having response as binary data , you can rename the file

Comment: check your response once again, are you really getting any response, or its simply a get url which on hitting handles download at server side